# cant install ubuntu 12.04 on my X86 pc

Tags: installation, 12.04

i tried to install ubuntu 12.04 but it said that you need the required kernal to install ubuntu 12.04. so unable to boot.
 so please help me to install it on my X86 pc( AMD processor with windows vista installed.)

Comment: Did you correctly download the amd ubuntu 12.04 iso and make a bootable pen drive with it?

Comment: i downloaded ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso and precise-desktop-i386.iso. and i created it using universal usb creator but it again show that i need the required kernal to install and thus unable to boot. please help me to install 12.04.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think you need the AMD version to install it on your system. The i386 version is for intel processors.

Comment: My bad. It seems that the iso you downloaded works for all the systems as per the detail here : http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ I do not know about universal usb creator. Do you have another ubuntu installation available somewhere? Then you can use "Startup disk creator" to make a bootable pen drive.

Comment: i successfully installed the ubuntu 11.10 on my same pc.but could not installed 12.04. i have tried to install on virtual box but all in vain.i cant install it

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete literal text of the message as it is displayed.

Comment: i mean it tells me that it requires a kernal and without it , unable to boot . therefore i tried to install it in virtual machine but it again displays the same thing. i also created the live usb to install and it displays the first screen to select the language but as soon as i select to install , it again displays the same and display that unable to boot. then i tried to install ubuntu 11.10 and it installed successfully.so please help me to install ubuntu 12.04 on my pc( with windows vista installed)

Comment: AMD or Intel processors both use '-i386' for 32bit install, and '-amd64' for 64bit.  For an older AMD processor, running Vista, start with 32bit.

Comment: Is the message you are getting saying something like this? `This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU`

Comment: Do **not** use this file `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso ` Use this file: `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso`

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions on Ubuntu Download page, to create an install CD/USB on your Windows platform.  This DOES require the 'bootloader', which is downloaded separately.

*Even better, have a friend with Ubuntu create a USB for you.  All needed tools, elements are now included in standard install (once installed).*

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your file integrity? Maybe the ISO file is not downloaded correctly.

You should test the integrity of the ISO file to make sure the file is downloaded correctly. If you have another Linux machine, use the `md5sum your-ubuntu-image.iso` command with your ISO file to find out the MD5 hash code. In my case, the command looks like this:

`md5sum ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso`

And the output is:

`128f0c16f4734c420b0185a492d92e52  ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso`

Then you can check if the resulting hash code matches with MD5SUMs provided by Canonical at [this link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/MD5SUMS).

If you don't have another Linux machine, you can also do this on a Windows machine by downloading a proper tool for file hash checking.

Comment: @Deepak rathi  Use the file `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso`. For this file the output would be: `d791352694374f1c478779f7f4447a3f ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso`

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same issue, I found a workdaround, stack your CD/USB in the driver. boot, press return then select your language, then press F6, disable all options and press return, you should now be able to boot from CD, then from there do a full install in the graphical interface

Comment: i checked all the options but i cant install ubuntu 12.04. it saying that i lacks the required kernals to install that.